# Handling the back button in a meteor android app

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, history, iron-router

I have built a Meteor app with a mobile app interface (using Ratchet), only designed to be run as an app. On each page, there is a "back" link that takes you back to the parent page. For example, if I go deep inside a hierarchy of page such as this one:

Home > Category > Post

I can use a link in the Post page that will take me back to the Category page. Now, the problem is, if **from this Category page** I hit the back button, it should have the same behaviour as clicking the back link on the page. (in this case, take me to the Home page) Sadly, this doesn't happen and I get taken back to the Post page.

On iPhone it is not a problem (as far as I know) since there is no actual back button built-in to the device. But on Android it gives me headaches, for example:

Say a user goes to a Post page that he can delete using a button shown on the page. When the post-deletion method finishes, I take the user back to the Category page:

```
Router.go('categoryPage', {'_id': categoryId});
```

Problem is: if the user hits the back button after deleting a post, he or she gets taken to a "not found" page, since the previous post has been deleted. Now I can avoid that by adding `replaceState: true` like this:

```
Router.go('categoryPage', {'_id': categoryId}, {replaceState: true});
```

But now when the user hits the back button from the Category page, he or she gets taken to the page that was there **before** the Post page, which was... the same Category page. So the button just does nothing on the first press.

I also tried to pushState the url of the desired page in each of my template's `rendered̀  function, to no avail (and what would I put in there for the Home page?):

```
Template.categoryPage.rendered = function () {
  history.pushState(null, null, Router.url('home'));
};

Template.postPage.rendered = function () {
  history.pushState(null, null, Router.url('categoryPage', {'_id': this.data.categoryId}));
};
```

Has anyone tackled this issue and/or would be able to drop some knowledge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as the back button is pressed, Cordova trigger a "backbutton" event, see [there](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton).

By listening to this event you should be able to override the default behavior and do what you want:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackButtonDown, false);

function onBackButtonDown(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  // Do what you want
  ...
}
```